# Raspberry pi camera send by 3G usb key

Tags: networking, raspicam, streaming-video

I have a Raspberry pi 3 with a connected EG usb key on it. The communication is established and works well.
In an other part, i have configured my Raspberry with a pi-camera. I can see in local network in firefox the result of the camera.
I have a server with an IP adress witch is connected to internet throught a proxy.

I know that the 3G key does not have a fixed IP. And I can't connect and  from outside to the camera. ( server connected on the raspberry )

What i would like to do is to send the streamed video to the server with only the 3G usb key network connected on my Raspberry. ( raspberry send video directly on the ip adress of the server )

Is it possible and if yes how?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you might use a ssh tunnel: this will enable to access the machine with the 3G dongle from the internet even though its IP address is not only variable, but not accessible. You can google for "ssh tunnel" or look https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup something called `Dynamic DNS` (DynDNS). This will give you an always accessible domain name, reachable from the outside.

There are plenty such solutions. Here are two sources:

- https://www.1and1.com/digitalguide/server/tools/free-dynamic-dns-providers-an-overview/
- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2004389-best-ddns-providers

Comment: I have look this solution. But if i understand what you propose i need a dyndns by rasperry. I want to send video flux on the server where the rasperry is connected to network by 3G usb key

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Not sure I understood if the raspberry pi is the client or server in your case, but it doesn't really matter :)

You install ngrok on the server machine, and then tell ngrok which port you want to publish. it will give you a random DNS on the free version, or you can pay and then reserve a DNS, then you can access you server from any internet-connected device.